# Java Spring-boot: how to return a list and not a single result?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm new to Java and using the Spring-Boot framework. I have implemented a small method that given a transactionId gives me the list of all objects having that transactionId. I just have problems managing the list in the ServiceImpl. as I can't get a list back instead of a single result.

Comment: The mapper is working for single entities?

Comment: Where do you face the issue? Which class fails to return a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mapper is working for a single instance of your entities, you can simply iterate over the entity collection and map one entity at a time. Or you use Java8 streams:

```
List<StoredMessageModTrackEntity> entityList = repo.findAllByTransactionId(transactionId);
return entityList.stream().map(mapper::toDtoMapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Unlike your example the above snippet will return an empty list, if `entityList` is empty. Unless you explicitly need to return `null` (by some weird API contract or similar) you should not use `null` for empty collections. This will just result in bulky code as all consumers will always need to check for `null`. If you really (and I mean really) need `null`, you can either keep your if-statement or use `Optional`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(entityList).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(list -> list.stream().map(mapper::toDtoMapper)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())).orElse(null);
```

Comment: Hello dpr! I tried to implement your code but keep giving me only one element, for safety I also insert the controller because maybe it can be the problem

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Simplest way would be to add some debug output. If there is more than one element in the list the above code will map all of them.